# TYPO3 10 Form finisher sends out two emails

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I have a weird problem with all forms on my TYPO3 10.4.17 site that use an email finisher. The finisher sends two identical emails per recipient every time.
Does anyone have an idea how I can get rid of the second message?

Thanks!

**fileadmin/form_definitions/testform.form.yaml**

```
renderingOptions:
  submitButtonLabel: Absenden
type: Form
identifier: testform
label: Testform
prototypeName: standard
finishers:
  -
    options:
      subject: Testform
      recipients:
        [my email address]: ''
      senderAddress: noreply@[...]
      senderName: ''
      addHtmlPart: true
      attachUploads: true
      translation:
        language: Standard
      useFluidEmail: false
      title: ''
    identifier: EmailToReceiver
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'Vorherige Seite'
      nextButtonLabel: 'Nächster Schritt'
    type: Page
    identifier: page-1
    label: Step
    renderables:
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Textarea
        identifier: textarea-1
        label: Textfeld
```

**First message:**

```
Return-Path: <noreply@[removed]>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.2 (2018-09-13) on [removed]
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.5 required=5.0 tests=ALL_TRUSTED,BAYES_00,
    HTML_MESSAGE autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no version=3.4.2
X-Original-To: [removed]
Delivered-To: [removed]
Received: from [127.0.0.1] [removed]
    by [removed] (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id A1C5915A145C
    for [removed]; Thu, 17 Jun 2021 13:24:59 +0200 (CEST)
From: noreply@[removed]
To: [removed]
Subject: Testform
X-Mailer: TYPO3
Message-ID: <22d072eef5791cebf35ebcecee59ba0f@[removed]>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 17 Jun 2021 13:24:59 +0200
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=p-G2S-8S

--p-G2S-8S
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


Textfeld: Test Inhalt



--p-G2S-8S
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://w=
ww.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  =
  <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF-8">=

    <meta name=3D"format-detection" content=3D"telephone=3Dno">
</head=
>
<body>
    <table width=3D"600" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" b=
order=3D"0">
       =20
            <tr>
               =20
           =
             <td width=3D"600" valign=3D"top" align=3D"left">Textfeld</td>=

                        <td width=3D"600" valign=3D"top" align=3D"left">=

                           =20
                                   =20
  =
                                          <table cellspacing=3D"0" border=
=3D"0">
                                                <tr>
          =
                                          <td>Test Inhalt</td>
          =
                                      </tr>
                             =
               </table>
                                       =20
      =
                         =20
                        </td>
              =
     =20
            </tr>
       =20
    </table>
</body>
</html>

--p-G2S-8S--
```

**Second message:**

```
Return-Path: <noreply@[removed]>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.2 (2018-09-13) on [removed]
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.5 required=5.0 tests=ALL_TRUSTED,BAYES_00,
    HTML_MESSAGE autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no version=3.4.2
X-Original-To: [removed]
Delivered-To: [removed]
Received: from [127.0.0.1] [removed]
    by [removed] (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 18ACB15A1492
    for [removed]; Thu, 17 Jun 2021 13:25:00 +0200 (CEST)
From: noreply@[removed]
To: [removed]
Subject: Testform
X-Mailer: TYPO3
Message-ID: <af16ae610105ae22a01ae6b0718f2cba@[removed]>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 17 Jun 2021 13:25:00 +0200
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=w50f9lfA

--w50f9lfA
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


Textfeld: Test Inhalt



--w50f9lfA
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://w=
ww.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  =
  <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF-8">=

    <meta name=3D"format-detection" content=3D"telephone=3Dno">
</head=
>
<body>
    <table width=3D"600" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" b=
order=3D"0">
       =20
            <tr>
               =20
           =
             <td width=3D"600" valign=3D"top" align=3D"left">Textfeld</td>=

                        <td width=3D"600" valign=3D"top" align=3D"left">=

                           =20
                                   =20
  =
                                          <table cellspacing=3D"0" border=
=3D"0">
                                                <tr>
          =
                                          <td>Test Inhalt</td>
          =
                                      </tr>
                             =
               </table>
                                       =20
      =
                         =20
                        </td>
              =
     =20
            </tr>
       =20
    </table>
</body>
</html>

--w50f9lfA--
```

Comment: I am just guessing because I had such a problem once with another plugin: The problem might be that you render content twice - thus the plugin code runs twice. In my case it was something in my main (layout) template where I was checking if a column would have any content (thus rendering once) - and then rendering the content (another time...). That time I was using the `v:content.render` ViewHelper from EXT:vhs (I didn't know any better back then....)

Comment: You have put me on the right track. The content of the page was only visible once in the FrontEnd, yet that is the solution:

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
I have rendered the content with

```
<f:format.raw>{CONTENT}</f:format.raw>
```

before. This leads to the described behavior for a form with mail-finisher. If the content is rendered with

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '0'}" />
```

everything is fine. Please see https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content/master/en-us/Installation/InsertingContentPageTemplate/Index.html for more details.